# javascript breaks out of while loop when the function is called again

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

So i have been working on javascript alert animations,

```
function addalert(text){
            if(alertid >= 100){
                alertid = 0;
            }

            document.body.innerHTML += ("<div id=\"" + alertid + "\" " + "class=\"alert\">" + text + "</div>");
            var top = parseInt($("#"+alertid).css('top'));
            while($("#"+alertid).css('top') > 0){
                setInterval($("#"+alertid).css({"top": $("#"+alertid).css("top") - 1,"opacity":$("#"+alertid).css("opacity") -0.1}), 100);

            }
            $("#"+alertid).css({"top":"0","opacity":"0"});
            alertid++;
            return;
        }
```

the problem is that when you call this function when the function is already called and the animation is ongoing, it just seems to break out of the animation.

edit:

i tried using jquery animate, it didnt work

```
function addalert(text){
            if(alertid >= 100){
                alertid = 0;
            }

            document.body.innerHTML += ("<div id=\"" + alertid + "\" " + "class=\"alert\">" + text + "</div>");

            $("#"+alertid).animate({"top":"0px","opacity":"0"}, {easing: "linear", duration: 2000, complete: function(){$("#"+alertid).remove()} });


            /*$("#"+alertid).css({"top":"0","opacity":"0"});*/

            alertid++;
        }
```

Comment: why don't you use `$('#'+alertid).animate(...)`?

Comment: You better re-think and do it another (better) way. Try using more of CSS.

Comment: I believe your understanding of `setInterval`... isn't correct. `setInterval` doesn't "pause" your code.

Comment: Please add some HTML and CSS so we can actually reproduce your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo using [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/). Note that the code needs the CSS also to be set correctly, or it will not work. More precisely the `div` that is animated must have its `position` style set.

To interrupt the ongoing animation when a new one must start, use [`.finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/). Here is a working snippet that shows two alerts, where the second one interrupts the first when its only half-way:

```js
var alertid = 0;
function addalert(text){
    if(alertid >= 100){
        alertid = 0;
    }
    // Finish any ongoing alert animation
    $('.alert:last()').finish();
    // Add the div in the jQuery way:
    $("<div>").attr('id', alertid).addClass('alert').text(text)
        .appendTo(document.body)
        .animate({
            top: "0px",
            opacity: "0"
         }, {
            easing: "linear", 
            duration: 2000, 
            complete: function(){
                // You can use `this` here:
                $(this).remove();
            } 
        });
    alertid++;
}

// Demo
$(function() {
    addalert('first alert');
    setTimeout(function () {
        addalert('second alert interrupted the first');
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.alert {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a animation library instead of creating own animations like that. For example, there's velocity js which performs really well.

I'm not sure if I understood your animation perfectly well, but I think that's what it did too:

For the stop part, I've created a little dummy that needs to be improved -- but you get the idea. Obviously the element should be deleted as well and so on...

```js
var animation;

$('#start').on('click', function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.bottom = '10px';
  el.style.right = '10px';
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Alert text'));
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  animation = $(el).velocity({
    translateY: document.body.scrollHeight * -1 + 'px',
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    duration: 4000
  });

});

$('#stop').on('click', function() {
  $(animation).velocity('stop');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.3.1/velocity.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">
  Start animation
</button>

<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```